# REG Expression: How to use regular expression to grep few lines from the command output

Tags: javascript

I have a (sample) an output looks exactly same as below. I wonder how
    can get the information in comments section from the output by using a
    java script regular expression.  Basically I want rani comments in one variable and geetha comments in another variable. Also, my req is to use only java script. Thank you
    very much in advance.

```
  ##############################################################################
    #                            test                                            #
    ##############################################################################
    # ID    #      name   #   address               #                    comment #
    ##############################################################################
    #1      #      rani   #   canada                #   first home adress: India # 
    #       #             #                             second home adress:   US #
    #       #             #                             third home adress: Can   # 
    #       #             #                             forth home adress: Japan #
    #       #             #                                                      #
    ##############################################################################
    #1      #      geetha #   canada                #   first home adress: India # 
    #       #             #                             second home adress:   US #
    #       #             #                             third home adress: Can   # 
    #       #             #                             forth home adress: Japan #
    ##############################################################################
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: there is no way that's your "exact" oputput... you have a script that returns all these hash symbols and stuff or is it json?

Comment: Good luck. Also where's your code? We don't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// `` string allows newline sumbols (no need '\n')
s1=`##############################################################################
#                            test                                            #
##############################################################################
# ID    #      name   #   address               #                    comment #
##############################################################################
#1      #      rani   #   canada                #   first home adress: India # 
#       #             #                             second home adress:   US #
#       #             #                             third home adress: Can   # 
#       #             #                             forth home adress: Japan #
#       #             #                                                      #
##############################################################################
#1      #      geetha #   canada                #   first home adress: India # 
#       #             #                             second home adress:   US #
#       #             #                             third home adress: Can   # 
#       #             #                             forth home adress: Japan #
##############################################################################`
s2 = s1.match(/ rani (([^#]|#(?!#))*)/)[1];
s3 = s2.replace(/[ #]+/g,' ');
console.log(s3)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Dimava. it worked as you posted.